# Updating state doesn't re-render child with props react-redux connect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've just started using React Redux, so I'm just messing around with it on some of my old stuff. 
I have a component that takes props:

```
 <DataTable dataType = {this.state.dataType} 
        drinkArray = {this.state.drinkArray} 
        foodArray = {this.state.foodArray} 
        sort = {this.sort}/>
```

All the DataTable does is map through whichever array is selected by dataType and display some info in a table.

```
<div sytle = {{textAlign: 'center'}}>
  {(this.props.dataType === 'food' &&
    <table className = 'foodTable'>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th  id = 'price' onClick = {(e) => {this.props.sort(e,'food')}}>Price</th>
          <th  id = 'stock' onClick = {(e) => {this.props.sort(e,'food')}}>Stock</th>
        </tr>
        {this.props.foodArray.map((x,i) => {
          return (
            <tr key ={i}>
              <td>{x.name}</td>
              <td>{x.price}</td
              <td>{x.stock}</td>
            </tr>
            )
          })
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )}
//etc.
```

Basically the issue is when I add connect to the DataTable component:

```
export default connect()(DataTable)
```

In this case, I was just messing around and did not intend to actually do anything, but this causes a weird behavior I couldn't explain. 
The sort function that I passed via props no longer caused the DataTable to re-render. However, if I change the dataType of the parent via a button click, the DataTable does re-render. Both the sort function and changing the dataType use setState(), and I know the sort function is being called and working correctly from logging it to the console. The parent is also re-rendered when the sort function is called. If I remove connect from the DataTable Component, the sort function once again re-renders the DataTable.

So really my question is why does changing one of the props via setState cause the child to re-render, but changing a different prop via setState does not? This is just a general curiosity question.

Answer (score 1):

`connect()` does a shallow comparison (as optimization) - probably `sort` only mutates an existing array, it should create a new object (new ref).